# Bash executes only ~/.profile but neither of ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc

Tags: command-line, bash, macos

I have a strange problem with bash:

I switch my default shell to `/bin/sh` from zsh and it doesn't execute `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` when I open a new terminal, it only executes `~/.profile`.

What could be the problem?

I could probably source `~/.bashrc` from `~/.profile` but that does't seem like a good idea, e.g. it would break if I changed to another shell again.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you read the `bash` manual under the heading `INVOCATION` which states:

```
   If bash is invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh as  closely
   as  possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well.  When invoked as an interactive login shell, or a non-
   interactive shell with the --login option, it first attempts to read and  execute  commands  from  /etc/profile  and
   ~/.profile,  in that order.  The --noprofile option may be used to inhibit this behavior.  When invoked as an inter-
   active shell with the name sh, bash looks for the variable ENV, expands its value if it is  defined,  and  uses  the
   expanded  value as the name of a file to read and execute.  Since a shell invoked as sh does not attempt to read and
   execute commands from any other startup files, the --rcfile option has no effect.  A non-interactive  shell  invoked
   with the name sh does not attempt to read any other startup files.  When invoked as sh, bash enters posix mode after
   the startup files are read.
```

A new terminal session in OS X/macOS always starts as a login shell.

Answer (score 0):

To get `/bin/sh` to execute `~/.bashrc` the same way `/bin/bash` does, you would have to do the following.

1. Add the following lines to `~/.profile`.

   ```
   LOGINSHELL=YES
   export ENV=~/.shrc
   ```
2. Create the file `~/.shrc` containing the following line.

   ```
   if [ "$LOGINSHELL" != "YES" ]; then  source ~/.bashrc; fi
   ```

To help in debugging, I usually add the following line to beginning of the `~/.profile` file.

```
export DEBUGSHELL=YES
```

This line can be commented out when done debugging, as shown below.

```
#export DEBUGSHELL=YES
```

Next, add conditional `echo` statements to the beginning and ending of the files such as `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.shrc` and others. For example, `~/.shrc` would contain the following.

```
if [ "$DEBUGSHELL" = "YES" ]; then echo entered .shrc; fi
if [ "$LOGINSHELL" != "YES" ]; then  source ~/.bashrc; fi
if [ "$DEBUGSHELL" = "YES" ]; then echo exited .shrc; fi
```

Another idea, that may be useful, is to create a file `~/.bashcm` to contain the commands that need to be executed for both login and interactive shells. For example, this is usually where I place my `alias` commands. You will also need to include the following line in both your `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` files.

```
source ~/.bashcm
```

Answer (score -1):

`/bin/sh` is not **bash**. It is Bourne Shell. Bash (Bourne Again Shell)'s location is `/bin/bash`. Change your default shell to bash to use `~/.bash_profile` instead of `~/.profile`

Comment: /bin/sh on OSX is bash but it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh as  closely   as  possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well. (from other answer)